# Go back after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with checking of a serial number (it doesn't matter). After checking number this page refreshes. I have a back button on the page and I need via this button go back to previous open page, not on page where I was when I tryed to check this number but the page which was before.  When I use `history.back()` browser showes me error. How it can be written with jquery to work?

Comment: Can you please provide us with a full copy and paste of the error message you're receiving, and a small sample of source code which demonstrates the problem if at all possible. Thank you.

Comment: Confirm Form Resubmission  - error in browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well, you want to `go back two times in window history` with that button in the refreshed page...
right?

If so.. then you need: **<kbd>window.history.go(-2)</kbd>**

History:

```
---------   ---------   ---------
|   1   |   |   2   |   |    3    |
| start |-->| check |-->|   page  |
|       |   |  snº  |   |refreshed|
|       |   |   &   |   |         |
|       |   |  page |   | button------
|       |   |refresh|   |         |  |
---------   ---------   -----------  |
    ^________________________________|
           window.history.go(-2)
```